# Problem of rank, trace, determinant and eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here is a problem and its solution that I translated from Korean (so it might contain some errors):

> Problem:
>
> For real n-by-n matrices $A,B$, suppose $xA+yB=I$ for non-zero real $x,y$ and $AB=0$.
>   Prove $$det(A+B) = \frac{1}{x^{\text{rank}(A)}y^{\text{rank}(B)}}.$$
>
> Solution:
>
> Let $A'=xA$ and $B'=yB$.
>
> Then $A'+B'=I$ and $A'B'=0$.
>
> Then it follows that $A'=A'^2$ and $B'=B'^2$.
>
> So the minimal polynomials of $A'$ and $B'$ divides $x^2-x$.
>   Thus the eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$. Therefore $A'$ and $B'$ are diagonalizable.
>   Let $V,W$ be the eigenspace of $A'$, $B'$ respectively corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.
>   Then $\text{trace}(A')=\text{dim}(V)$ and $\text{trace}(B')=\text{dim}(W)$.
>
> (*) Also $\text{trace}(A')+\text{trace}(B')=n$.
>   Thus $\text{dim}(V \cap W)=0$ and $R^n=V \oplus W$ (direct sum).
>
> (**) Thus 
>   $$\text{det}(A+B)= \frac{1}{x}^{\text{dim}(V)} \frac{1}{y}^{\text{dim}(W)}=\frac{1}{x}^{\text{trace}(A')} \frac{1}{y}^{\text{trace}(B')}=\frac{1}{x^{\text{rank}(A)}y^{\text{rank}(B)}}$$

My question:

1) Why (*) holds?

2) Why (**) holds?

I know that the sum of eigenvalues equals $\text{trace}(A)$ and the multiple equals $\text{det}(A)$. Thank you.

Comment: For (1) you were already told that A'+ B'= I.  Then det(A')+ det(B')= det(A'+ B')= det(I)= n where n is the order of the matrices.

Comment: To get $\oplus$, use `\oplus`.

Comment: @user247327: det(I) = 1, not $n$.

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1}$ has eigenvalues that are all 1s, but it's not diagonalizable. $\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$ has eigenvalues of $0$ and $1$, but is not diagonalizable. So the "Therefore $A'$ and $B'$ are diagonalizable" seems to need at least a little clarification. Is this supposed to be a consequence of the eigenvalues alone, or the eigenvalues *and* something else?

Comment: @JohnHughes It's a property of a minimal polynomial. If the minimal polynomial is a product of 'distinct' linear factors, then it is diagonalizable. In this problem, we don't know what exactly the minimal polynomial is but we do know that it is a factor of x(x-1), which cannot have any root with multiplicity greater than 1.

Comment: **For future reference** While someone editing this question he/she accidentally ignored what I edited later, which includes the change from 'characteristic polynomial' to 'minimal polynomial.' Now I restored it.

Comment: I knew that; what puzzled me was that you say "the eigenvalues are 0 and 1, therefore $A'$ and $B'$ are diagonalizable." The reason they're diagonalizable is that their minimal polynomials divide $x(x-1)$, hence contain at most linear factors ... the eigenvalues could have been $17$ and $\pi$, and the result would have been just as valid. So while the proof is correct, the "therefore" misleads the reader into thinking that there's something special about $0$ and $1$, rather than about the polynomial having only linear factors; consider this a stylistic rather than mathematical suggestion.

Comment: @JohnHughes I'll be careful next time. I think I wrote like that because if I write 'Thus the eigenvalues are 0 or 1 and A′ and B′ are diagonalizable.', then two 'and's may confuse others. Probably I'll use 'also' instead of 'therefore.' Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's not true that the characteristic polynomial of $A'$ (or $B'$) must divide $x^2 - x$. What is true is that the minimal polynomial of $A'$ (or $B'$) must divide $x^2 - x$ and hence $A'$ (and $B'$) is diagonalizable with **possible** eigenvalues $0,1$.

Since $A' + B' = I$, we get 
$$ \operatorname{trace}(A' + B') = \operatorname{trace}(A') + \operatorname{trace}(B') = \dim V + \dim W = \operatorname{trace}(I_n) = n. $$

Since $A'B' = 0$, if $v \in V \cap W$ then $0 = A' B'v = A'v = v$ which shows that $V \cap W = \{ 0 \}$. This, together with $\dim V + \dim W = n$ implies that $\mathbb{R}^n = V \oplus W$. Finally, the eigenvalues of $cB' + dI$ are $d$ with multiplicity $\dim V$ and $c + d$ with multiplicity $\dim W$. Hence,

$$ \det(A + B) = \det \left( \frac{1}{x} \left( xA + yB + (x - y)B \right) \right) = \det \left( \frac{1}{x} I +  \frac{x-y}{y}B' \right) \\ = \frac{1}{x}^{\dim V} \left( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{x - y}{y} \right)^{\dim W} = \frac{1}{x}^{\dim V} \frac{1}{y}^{\dim W}.$$

Answer (score 2):

First, we should show that $(A')^2 = A'$.  First, note that $A'$ commutes with $B'$, since $B = I - A'$ is a "polynomial" on $A$. Now,
$$
I = (A' + B')^2 = (A')^2 + (B')^2 + 2A'B'= (A')^2 + (B')^2\\
= (A')^2 + (I - A')^2 = 2(A')^2 - 2A' + I
$$
Rearrange $I = 2(A')^2 - 2A' + I$ to find $(A')^2 = A'$. Similarly for $B'$.

To prove (*): note that
$$
n = \operatorname{Tr}(I) = \operatorname{Tr}(A' + B') = \operatorname{Tr}A' + \operatorname{Tr}B'
$$
To see that $V \cap W = \{0\}$, note that any $v \in V \cap W$ would satisfy $A'B'v = v$.

To prove (**): it suffices to consider $A'$ to $B'$ with respect to a basis that diagonalizes both.

Answer (score 1):

They are good tricks.

As for (*) 
Because $A`+B`=I$, $Tr(A`)+Tr(B`)=n$.

And if $dim(V \cap W)\ne 0$, there exists a $X \in V\cap W$. Then $ABX=AX=X$. However, $AB=0$, that's a conflict.

So $dim(V \cap W)= 0$.

As for (**) First we notice that W is the eigenspace of $A`$ corresponding to the eigenvalue 0, because $A`B`=0$. And the same to V.

Because $R^n=V(+)W$, when we diagonalize $A`$, $B`$ is also diagonal. 
So we can calculate $$det(A+B)=det(\frac{1}{x}A`+\frac{1}{y}B`)$$