# Problem of eigenvalue, eigenspace, and direct sum.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Help me understanding the solution I've been reading:

$A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ real matrices. $A'=xA$, $B'=yB$ for nonzero real $x$ and $y$.

From the other conditions given to this problem (which I omitted and just going to state the results) we know that $A'$ and $B'$ are diagonalizable and possible eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$. Define $V$ and $W$ be the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $1$ of $A'$ and $B'$ respectively. And we also know that $\mathbb R^n = V \oplus W$.

Let a basis of $V$ and $W$ be $\{v_1,\dots,v_p\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_q\}$ respectively.

(*) Then $\{v_1,\ldots,v_p,w_1, ...,w_q\}$ becomes a basis composed of the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues $\frac1x$, $\frac1y$ of $A+B=\frac1xA'+\frac1yB'$.

(**) From this, we have $$\det(A+B)= \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\dim (V)}\left( \frac{1}{y}\right)^{\dim (W)}.$$

I need an explanation of (*) and (**). Especially for (*), I don't understand what the text says. I thought there are no (good) relationship between $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ in terms of eigenvalues.

Also what's the relationship between $A+B$ and $V+W$ in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rephrasing of the original problem lacks some information which is crucial for the result to hold.  Let's go back to the [original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386829/problem-of-rank-trace-determinant-and-eigenvalue/2386886#2386886) and see how every piece of information is used to get the required result. You are given that $A' + B' = I$ and $A'B' = 0$.

1. The first observation is that by multiplying $A' + B' = I$ by $A'$ from the left and using $A'B' = 0$, we get $A'^2 = A'$. Similarly, by multiplying the identity by $B'$ from the right, we get $B'^2 = B'$. Those conditions tell you that $A',B'$ are projections so they are diagonalizable with possible eigenvalues $0,1$.
2. Let's assume we are given a projection $P = P^2$. Any vector $v \in \mathbb{F}^n$ decomposes as $v = Pv + (v - Pv)$ where $Pv \in \operatorname{im}(P)$ and $v - Pv \in \ker(P)$ (since $P(v - Pv) = Pv - P^2v = 0$). Hence, $\mathbb{F}^n = \operatorname{ker}(P) + \operatorname{im}(P)$. Since $n = \dim \operatorname{ker}(P) + \dim \operatorname{im}(P)$, this is a direct sum decomposition so $\ker(P) \oplus \operatorname{im}(P) = \mathbb{F}^n$. The image $\operatorname{im}(P)$ is also the eigenspace of $P$ associated to the eigenvalue $1$ while the kernel is the eigenspace of $P$ associated to the eigenvalue $0$. To see why, note that $\ker(P - I) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(P)$ while if $v = Pw \in \operatorname{im}(P)$ then $Pv = P^2w = Pw = v$. Finally, the map $Q = I - P$ also satisfies $Q^2 = Q$ so it is a projection whose image is $\ker(P)$ and whose kernel is $\operatorname{im}(P)$ (check this!).
3. Consider the space $V$ which is the eigenspace of $A'$ associated to the eigenvalue $1$. By the previous item, $V$ is **also** the kernel of $I - A' = B'$. Similarly, $W$ is **also** the kernel of $I - B' = A'$. In particular, we have $V \oplus W = \mathbb{R}^n$.
4. Using the above, we see now that if $v \in V$ and $w \in W$ then
   $$ (A + B)v = \frac{A'}{x}v + \frac{B'}{y}v = \frac{v}{x} + 0 = \frac{v}{x}, \\
   (A + B)w = \frac{A'}{x}w + \frac{B'}{y}w = 0 + \frac{w}{y} = \frac{w}{y}$$
   so indeed $V$ is the eigenspace of $A + B$ associated to the eigenvalue $\frac{1}{x}$ and $W$ is the eigenspace of $A + B$ associated to the eigenvalue $\frac{1}{y}$.
5. Since $\det(A + B)$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $A + B$, we immediately get
   $$ \det(A + B) = \frac{1}{x}^{\operatorname{dim} V} \frac{1}{y}^{\operatorname{dim} W}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much. Now a question arises: why do we need the fact that $ R^n=V \oplus W $ ?

Comment: Plus, in your 2 and 3, the fact that V is a subset of the eigenspace of B' associated with 0 (A+B associated with 1/x) is clear but why the converse also?

Comment: @Cauchy: You don't really need $\mathbb{R}^n = V \oplus W$ but you need to know that you can find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of eigenvectors of both $A'$ and $B'$. By definition, elements of $V$ are eigenvectors of $A'$ but it is not clear that they are eigenvectors of $B'$. By definition, elements of $W$ are eigenvectors of $B'$ but it is not clear that they are eigenvectors of $A'$. Finally, it is not clear that you can form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by choosing linearly independent vectors from $V$ and $W$. The latter is pretty much equivalent to $V \oplus W = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Cauchy: I've edited my answer to include a general fact about projections which can be used to solve the exercise and implies that the eigenspace of $B'$ associated to the eigenvalue $0$ is precisely $V$.

Comment: Can't I just say that since V is a subset of the eigenspace of A+B associated with the eigenvalue 1/x and W with 1/y respectively and dimV+dimW=n(maximum possible number since A+B is n-by-n), the eigenspaces of A+B with respect to 1/x and 1/y are exactly V and W?

Comment: You also need to know that $V \cap W = \{ 0 \}$ (which together with $\dim V + \dim W = n$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n = V \oplus W$). The equation $\dim V + \dim W = n$ alone does not rule out the possibility that $V = W$ (with $\dim V = \dim W = \frac{n}{2}$) and $x = y$.

Comment: What if I just separate the two cases(x=y and otherwise)? Then the reasoning looks fine to me even without $ V ∩ W $ = {0}.

Comment: Let's say $x = y$. Then $V + W$ is clearly contained in the eigenspace of $A + B$ associated to $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{y}$. How do you conclude that $V + W$ is the whole space (as it should be)?

Comment: Why do we need that $V+W$ is the whole $R^n$? I do care is that the eigenspace of 1/x has dimension dimV and 1/y has dimW. Even if x=y then 1/x has dimension dimV+dimW. Then the required inequality holds anyway.

Comment: @Cauchy: But you use the fact that the determinant is the product of **all** the eigenvalues. For that you need to know the operator is diagonalizable and that you have found all the eigenvalues with multiplicities. If $\dim (V + W) < n$, the determinant won't be $\frac{1}{x}^{\dim V} \frac{1}{y}^{\dim W}$.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $V\oplus W=\mathbb{R}^m$, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_p\}$ is a basis ov $V$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_q\}$ is a basis of $W$, then $\{v_1,\ldots,w_q\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, what is $A+B$? It's the linear map from $V\oplus W$ into itself such that $v+w\mapsto A.v+B.w$ ($v\in V$ and $w\in W$). Since $(A+B).v_k=A.v_k=\frac1xv_k$ and $(A+B).w_l=B.w_l=\frac1yw_l$, the basis has the property described at the text.
2. I suppose that this is clear now. The matrix of $A+B$ (note this this is *not* the sum of two matrices) is a diagonal matrix with $\dim V$ $\frac1x$'s and $\dim W$ $\frac1y$'s. Therefore its determinant is $\left(\frac1x\right)^{\dim V}\left(\frac1y\right)^{\dim w}$.